# Markdown syntax inside Jekyll Liquid results in plaintext rendering

Tags: markdown, jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to list my posts like so, using Jekyll's Liquid:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
    - [ {{ post.title }} ]( {{ post.url }} )
{% endfor %}
```

As far as I understand it, this should produce markdown similar to:

---

- [Example Website](http://example.com)

---

However, it simply substitutes the URL and title but returns plaintext:

```
- [Example Website](http://example.com)
```

Comment: Were are you using this? If in a Markdown document, then yes, it would produce the Markdown which would then be passed through the Markdown parser and converted to HTML. However, if it is not in a Markdown document, then it would never get passed through a Markdown parser and remain as unprocessed Markdown text.

Comment: @Waylan It's in a markdown (.md) document. Adding markdown to the page outside of the loop renders normally.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was caused by the whitespace of 4 spaces indenting the list item, which caused Markdown's formatting to treat the entire line as a block of code. As it was a block of code, Jekyll did not render any further Markdown syntax inside it.

The problem was resolved by removing the whitespace like so:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
- [ {{ post.title }} ]( {{ post.url }} )
{% endfor %}
```